# Getting JSON from the Reddit Search API

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp, reddit

I'm trying to load some Reddit data for a search based on a URL and I keep getting the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` on line 1 of submit.json. I opened submit.json in inspector and checked - the JSON is valid. So, what am I doing wrong? I've tried demos for things like subreddit searching, and this format works fine, it just doesn't seem to work for search.

```
function loadReddit() {
  var exampleURL = "http://www.reddit.com/submit.json?url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4dT8FJ2GE0&sort=comments";
  $.ajax({
    url: exampleURL,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }     
  });
}
```

I've posted a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bwgT6/1/) with the code, feel free to edit if you feel it is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're making a JSONP request but the API is giving you a plain JSON response. In JSONP the response JSON is wrapped in a function call, and it's convention that the function's name is given by the `callback` URL parameter. jQuery generates this parameter for you, but unfortunately Reddit's API is ignoring it.

I had to Google "Reddit API JSONP" to figure it out, but it turns out Reddit expects the parameter to be called `jsonp` instead of `callback`. So the solution is use the `jsonp` option to tell jQuery to put the callback name in the `jsonp` parameter:

```
var resourceUrl = "http://www.reddit.com/submit.json",
    params      = { url:  "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4dT8FJ2GE0",
                    sort: "comments" }
;

$.ajax({
  url: resourceUrl,
  data:     params,   // let jQuery deal with URL parameters for you
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonp:    "jsonp",  // the name of the URL parameter for jQuery to give the
                      // callback function's name in    
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }     
});
```

This will result in jQuery making a call to a URL like this:

```
http://www.reddit.com/submit.json
  ? jsonp = jQuery202033503812667913735_1384877326437
  & url   = http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3De4dT8FJ2GE0
  & sort  = comments
  & _     = 1384877326438
```

The `jsonp` and `_` parameters are randomly generated by jQuery. (The `_` is meant to force the browser to make a new request instead of the cached result of a previous request. This is [documented](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) under, and can be controlled by, the cache option.)

Comment: Thanks. Great solution and explanation. Much appreciated.